# If $f^2(b) - f^2(a) = b^2 - a^2$, then the equation $f'(x)f(x) = x$ has at least one root in (a, b).

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $f$ is continuous on [a, b] and differentiable on the open 
interval (a, b). How to  that if $f^2(b) - f^2(a) = b^2 - a^2$,

then the equation

$f'(x)f(x) = x$

has at least one root in (a, b).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider
$$
F(x)=f^2(x)-x^2
$$
and apply Rolle's theorem